# a 2 TB data disk mount on a 200GB ubuntu cause no space left on disk?

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have a 200GB ubuntu machine on the cloud.

and I mount a 2TB data disk on the machine..

```
root@ubuntu:/# sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/vda: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders, total 419430400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000da36d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/vda1   *        2048   419428351   209713152   83  Linux
```

but then the data in my vda1 use 130GB ..
and the data in my ubuntu machine used about 70GB

the liunx system keep saying that the no space left on device???
so what's the problem here..I why the mounted disk use the space on my 200GB disk>>that's strange..

```
x@ubuntu:~$ df
Filesystem                              1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev                                      8206052         8    8206044   1% /dev
tmpfs                                     1643380       416    1642964   1% /run
/dev/vda1                               206291640 183228440   12561196  94% /
none                                            4         0          4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                                         5120         0       5120   0% /run/lock
none                                      8216900         0    8216900   0% /run/shm
none                                       102400         0     102400   0% /run/user
data.disk:/data.disk/produ__uploads 2064114688 235497472 1723743232  13% /var/www/myblog.com/uploads
```

really need help.

```
root@ubuntu:/# df -hi
Filesystem                             Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                                     2.0M   424  2.0M    1% /dev
tmpfs                                    2.0M   352  2.0M    1% /run
/dev/vda1                                 13M  255K   13M    2% /
none                                     2.0M     2  2.0M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                                     2.0M     2  2.0M    1% /run/lock
none                                     2.0M     1  2.0M    1% /run/shm
none                                     2.0M     2  2.0M    1% /run/user
data.disk:/data.disk/produ_uploads   125M  415K  125M    1% /var/www/myblog.com/uploads
```

Comment: have you run out of inodes?  (use `df -hi` to view)

Comment: @guiverc I update the df -hi info.plz help..

Comment: Just to make sure: Is the mountpoint /var/www/myblog.com/uploads an empty directory? (umount `data.disk:/data.disk/produ_uploads` and check)

Comment: @muclux it's in production server ,and full off user data.umount is not an opthion..